# Passing data from a for loop to a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I have just started out learning few things in python, I am stuck in between.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

ticker = ['20MICRONS.NS', '21STCENMGM.NS', '3IINFOTECH.NS', '3MINDIA.NS', '3PLAND.NS']

for i in ticker:
    try:
        quote = si.get_quote_table(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(quote.items())
        df = df.append(quote.items(), ignore_index=True)
        
    except (ValueError, IndexError,TypeError):
      continue
print(df)
```

Just for example: The value of i has more than 4 entries, whenever I am exiting the loop this data has to be added or should be appended in the dataframe.
But for some reason the dataframe is not appending these values.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more code? I'm not sure what get_quote_table() is doing or what's in ticker or what si is.

Comment: Hello Dsteman, Sure..
import yahoo_fin.stock_info as si

ticker = ['20MICRONS.NS', '21STCENMGM.NS', '3IINFOTECH.NS', '3MINDIA.NS', '3PLAND.NS']

Basically I have imported the Yahoo_fin from which I get the stocks related information and ticker will be the stocks related data.
get_quote_table -- will extract the data found on the summary page of a stock

Comment: where did you create the empty dataframe to begin with?

Comment: `for i in ticker:
        try:
            quote = si.get_quote_table(i)
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(quote.items())
            df = df.append(quote.items(), ignore_index=True)
        
        except (ValueError, IndexError,TypeError):
          continue
    print(df)`

I have declared the empty dataframe in the for loop itself.
Should I be declaring it elsewhere?

Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please add the code in the question, not in the comments. Makes our lives easier :)

Comment: @DSteman 
I'm So sorry for causing trouble.
I have updated the full code in the question itself.

Comment: No problem! Did this solve your problem? If yes, please click the check mark next to the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined df within the loop, which means that a new dataframe is initialised in df at each iteration. Define a new dataframe in df before the loop and append to the df in the loop. Please add the information that you provided in the comments to the question.